# Laravel leftjoin not working when no matching item found on the right tables

Tags: laravel

```
$requests=DB::table('requisitions')
    ->leftJoin('items', 'items.cSimpleCode', '=', 'requisitions.product_code')
    ->leftJoin('price_uploads', 'price_uploads.item_CodeSAP', '=',
           'requisitions.product_code')
    ->select('requisitions.*', 'price_uploads.fze_price',
         'price_uploads.currency', 'items.stocklink',
         'items.description', 'requisitions.current_stock_<_90 as less_stock',
         'requisitions.current_stock_>_90 as more_stock')
    ->where('requisitions.requisition_id', $request ->input('requisition_id'))
    ->where('price_uploads.pricing_type', $request ->input('pricelist_id'))
    ->get();
```

The above code works well with join but what i intend is to get all requisitions item regards if they are in item or price_uploads unfortunately a get am empty result when i use item that are not contained in the items and price uploads. i dont know why leftjoin is not working

Comment: hi mannu, i wanted to clarify, you want to get all `requisitions` **regardless** its in `items` or `price_uploads`? have you tried to remove the `where` clause and see if the query returns anything?

Comment: Hi yes when i remove the where condition it works well. But the where clause is required since one item can have more than one price list that is defined in the database so a user has to select which price for that item he/she intends to use

Comment: I guess what @BagusTesa clarified here is that `leftJoin` does work. You are only filtering out the results with your `where` statement

Comment: i have no idea how your table looked like and how they are related. however, `->where('price_uploads.pricing_type', $request ->input('pricelist_id'))` is this part correct? `pricing_type` has to match to `pricelist_id`?

Comment: I have seen where the problem is. it is in where clause seems you cant use a column from the left table in the where clause. I don't know how to do the script since am using excel to upload items and assigning a unique id for all the items in that excel and thats what am using to group items